# How to pass values in UE2Runtime to UnrealScript?

Tags: unreal

We have a game that launches via vbscript and calls UE2Runtime:

```
set demofile = filesys.GetFile("..neuro2\Inifiles\"&usrFoldername&"\LostWorld.ini")       
'WShell.Run "..\System\UE2Runtime.exe LW1_basic.urt?Class=neuro2.Exp2Subject -log=" & usrName & "_training.log"
```

How do you grab the value in `usrName` that is passed to UE2Runtime to a console command in UnrealScript 2 when certain events are triggered in the game?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: UE2? Wow, that's almost historic :)

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it!!!! And I am having sooooooo much trouble finding documentation. I know there are docs.unrealengine.com and wiki.beyondunreal.com and some other scattered around, but lots of the links are dead and there's just not enough info available specifically for UE2 (so newer functions etc.). I also have the UnrealScript Game Programming Cookbook and UDK Game Programming with UnrealScript -- but those also aren't helping me out much....so HELP!!!

Comment: I have almost no knowledge about UE2, sorry. Is there a reason you don't switch to UE4?

Comment: I read in the forums that the engines are too different to port from UE2 to UE4 or even UE2:
https://forums.unrealengine.com/archive/index.php/t-63122.html
Plus we already have the game ready in UE2....